# How to get label activity reports ( O365 Data Governance) user level and file level programatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-security, data-governance

I used labels and policies in Data Governance. After I auto-published the label, I see the individual files in OneDrive getting tagged with a label.

I need to programmatically check if there are any labels associated with the file and categorize them. I don't see the labels data while querying through Graph as well.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/test.txt

Do we have any powershell commands or REST API to get these data in granular level?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/view-label-activity-for-documents?redi...

Thanks,
Madhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this for retrieving LabelActivity:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance-retention/get-compliancetag?view=exchange-ps](http://%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/policy-and-compliance-retention/get-compliancetag?view=exchange-ps)

For your first question on retrieving Labels from Graph, you can try the below query to check if it provides label info. I haven't tried myself.

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields](http://%20https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D?expand=fields)

You can constructSharePointId using the information from SharePointIds from the query below:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root/children?$select=Name,sharepointIds

Comment: Yes Pallav. I actually found a way through CSOM and SharePoint Rest API to get the column values for each files/folders. the above query provided by you also works. I was trying to find a way in the file/folder level which will reduce the complexity